# splitting on pipe character in perl

Tags: perl, split, awk

I have a little problem. I want to split a line at every pipe character found using the split operator. Like in this example.

```
echo "000001d17757274585d28f3e405e75ed|||||||||||1||||||||||||||||||||||||" | \
perl -ane '$data = $_ ; chop $data ; @d = split(/\|/ , $data) ; print $#d+1,"\n" ;'
```

I would expect an ouput of 36
as `awk` splitting with the delimiter `|` return 36, but instead I get 12, as if the split stopped at the `1` character in the line.

```
echo "000001d17757274585d28f3e405e75ed|||||||||||1|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||" | \ 
awk -F"|" '{print NF}'
```

Any idea. I have tried many ways of quoting the `|`, but without success. 
Many thanks by advance.

Answer (score 18):

According to [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> By default, empty leading fields are preserved, and **empty trailing ones are deleted**.

You need to specify a negative limit to the split to get the trailing ones:

```
split(/\|/, $data, -1)
```

Comment: So many thanks. I have done this kind of splits so many times and never fell into this trap before.

Comment: +1 - Most people don't realize this until they run into this exact circumstance, and they check. Programmatically, it makes no difference. If I want to test whether a value is defined `if (defined $my_array[$field])` will work whether or not there's actually an entry `$my_array[$field]` whose value is undefined or whether there is no defined field `$my_array[$field]`.

Comment: "Programatically", there are huge differences. e.g. `for (@myarray)`, `join($sep, @myarray)`, etc